# Wrong result trying to plot a spider-web graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph

I am practicing how to use the matplotlib and pyplot library, and for that very reason I'm trying to make a function that plots points so that any two points have a line that
connects them.

I think I'm close to solving the problem, but the result still seems a bit off.

My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = (np.sqrt(2)/2)
square_points = ((0, 0),(1, 0),(0, 1),(1, 1))
shape_points = ((1, 0),(alpha, alpha),(0, 1),(-alpha, alpha),(-1, 0),(-alpha, -alpha),(0, -1),(alpha, -alpha))


def complete_graph(points):
    for i in range(len(points)):
        for j in range(i):
            x = (points[i])
            y = (points[j])
            plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

complete_graph(square_points)   #square shape
complete_graph(shape_points)    #spider web ish shape
```

The result is supposed to look like this:
**Square shape**

[image]

**Spider web shape**

[image]

My result however is:

**For what is supposed to be a square shape:**
[image]

[image]

**For what is supposed to be a spiderweb-ish shape**
[image]

Comment: @JohanC: That solved it! Thanks a mill!

Comment: @JohanC i believe you should write an answer.

Comment: @JohanC: If you write an answer, I will accept it as the solution. The least I can do is reward you with some points for the magnificent help you provided:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the x and y coordinates separately.  The simplest would be `x=[points[i][0], points[j][0]]` and `y=[points[i][1], points[j][1]]`.

Using numpy, the code could be written creating all x. The vertices can be drawn using `plt.scatter()`. Setting the z-order to 3 shows them in front of the edges.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

alpha = np.sqrt(2) / 2
square_points = ((0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1))
shape_points = ((1, 0), (alpha, alpha), (0, 1), (-alpha, alpha), (-1, 0), (-alpha, -alpha), (0, -1), (alpha, -alpha))

def complete_graph(points):
    # calculate and plot the edges
    edges = np.array([(points[i], points[j]) for i in range(len(points)) for j in range(i)]).reshape(-1, 2)
    plt.plot(edges[:, 0], edges[:, 1], color='dodgerblue')
    points = np.array(points)
    # plot the vertices
    plt.scatter(points[:, 0], points[:, 1], color='mediumvioletred', s=100, zorder=3)
    plt.axis('equal')  # show squares as squares (x and y with the same distances)
    plt.axis('off')  # hide the surrounding rectangle and ticks
    plt.show()

complete_graph(square_points)  # square shape
complete_graph(shape_points)  # spider web ish shape
```

[image: two complete graphs]

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem perfectly! One other question though. In the image I posted in the description, the outer points are colored pink. Do you know how that was done also? It looks like your kind of god with matplotlib, to say the least:-)